# equation of level surface at given point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> The equation of level surface to the function $g(x,y,z)=\cos(x^2-y+z^2)$ that pass through the point $(-1,2,1)$ is

What i have try

$g_{x}(x,y,z)\bigg|_{(-1,2,1)}=-\sin(x^2-y+z^2)\cdot 2x\bigg|_{(-1,2,1)}=0$

$g_{y}(x,y,z)\bigg|_{(-1,2,1)}=-\sin(x^2-y+z^2)\cdot -\bigg|_{(-1,2,1)}=0$

$g_{z}(x,y,z)\bigg|_{(-1,2,1)}=-\sin(x^2-y+z^2)\cdot 2z\bigg|_{(-1,2,1)}=0$

So equation of level surface at point $(-1,2,1)$ is

$0(x+1)+0(y-2)+0(z-1)=0$

But i have seems that this does not make any sense

Please help me to solve it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint.* Evaluate the function at the given point to get a constant $c.$ Then the desired level surface is $g(x,y,z)=c.$

Comment: i did not get your point. Did you mean $g(-1,2,1)=\cos(1-2+1)=\cos 0=1.$ please explain me in detail. Thanks

Comment: @jacky Yes, you've found that $c=1.$ Now set the given function equal to $c.$ Then you have your level surface.

Comment: You mean that our final  answer is  $f(x,y,z)=\cos(x^2-y+z^2)-1=0.$

Comment: @jacky Almost. Remove the $f(x,y,z)=.$